# Calculate limit $(\frac{2x+1}{x-1})^x$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: limits

I have to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{2x+1}{x-1} \right)^x$$

---

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{2x+1}{x-1} \right)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{x+2}{x-1} \right)^x=\infty$$

But is $2^\infty$, isn't that indeterminate like $1^\infty$? For example we know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=1^\infty \ne 1$

Comment: Well, $2^n$, when $n \to \infty$ is pretty clear at the very least... The problem is not there. The proble is to prove properly things.

Comment: hmm so what is the proper way?

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, it is useful to remark that $\dfrac{2x+1}{x-1}=2+\dfrac{3}{x-1}$

So for $x>1$ you have $\dfrac{2x+1}{x-1}>2$

You can finsih from here...

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2x+1}{x-1}>2$$
hence your limit exceeds $$\lim_{x\to\infty}2^x.$$